# Angular/Rxjs get sync data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

Whether there method getting data sync from http.get ? I want use data inside component in order to set `router.resetConfig()`.

Data from http.get = [{path: 'site/a', component: Component}, {path: 'site/b', component: Component}...].

I tried to use `BehaviorSubject`, `next()`, `switchMap` but always I must to use `.subscribe()`.

```js
class A {
    data = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
    url = 'url';

    constructor() {
        this.getUrl();
        console.log(this.data.value);
    }

    getUrl() {
        this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
            map(result => {
                this.data.next(result)
            }));
    }
}
```

If I use subscribe()

```js
this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(result => result)).subscribe(data => {this.data.next(data)});
```

If `console.log(this.data)` value exist, `console.log(this.data.value)` not exist.

I want to get:

```js
router.resetConfig(this.data.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you get from your `http.get` is an array. You don't need to modify any data in the array instead you just want to pass the data as is. So what you need to do instead is just pass an observable from your `getUrl` function and `subscribe` to it where you want to get the data. Since `http.get` returns an `Observable`, you can just return your `http.get` in `getUrl`.

I would also suggest you move the logic from your `constructor` to your `ngOnInit` as that's the best practice. (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#call-it-in-ngoninit))

```js
import { Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

class A {
    url = 'url';

    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUrl().subscribe((data: Routes) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.router.resetConfig(data);
        });
    }

    getUrl(): Observable<Routes> {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }
}
```

It would also be suggested to move all your http calls to a service. (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#why-write-a-service))

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-reset-config).

Comment: I want to receive data without .subscribe()

Comment: router.resetConfig() set in this way does not work, data must be sync

Comment: My bad, it's supposed to be just `data`, not `this.data`. Regarding, your first comment, you are dealing with async data, so you have to use either promises or observables. Why exactly do you want to receive data without .subscribe()?

Comment: Data inside router.resetConfig() must be sync. 
Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Previously I had used `this.data` by mistake, this was a typo. If you use just `data`, you will get the right value.

Comment: I know you made a mistake. The effect will be like the example from BehaviorSubject. Array looks like it is empty although it contains elements that cannot be called, forEach... 
If data is sync {const a = [{path: ''} ...]; router.Config (a)}, everything is ok if inside .subscribe() not working. Analogously is with this.data.next();

Comment: So I would like to somehow emit the last value and write to the variable in a synchronous way. I am thinking of combineLatest, Sheduler ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are asking for. I have added a simple Stackblitz example where you can update the config. The `Observable.of` returns an observable similar to `http.get`

Comment: How you do the same with http.get will not work. Observable.of emit notification with data sync. This is the effect I want to get from http get.

Comment: If you use `of ('[{path:' '}]').subscribe (data => this.value = data);` you can use `this.value` outside `.subscribe ()`. If you use `http.get ().subscribe (data => this.value = data)` you cannot use `this.value` outside `.subscribe ()`. As far as I know `Observable.of `uses `Scheduler` and emits a `complete ()` notification.

Comment: The above method of using `of` to mock `http.get` data is the same method used by angular in the docs. They both return an observable (See https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-heroes-with-httpclient). There must something wrong with your api. What exactly are you getting when you subscribe to http observable and console the data? You should be getting the route array config.

Comment: It happens exactly what I write all the time. If you set `restConfig()`
same using `http.get` this won't work because http.get doesn't send `complete()` notifications. Try it yourself if you want and you'll find that it's not the same.

Comment: If I use `console.log(this.router.config)` I will get an empty array containing for example 10 elements. The array is as if empty even though it contains elements. Cannot call any of the items and routing does not work. If I use `of()`, everything works normally, the array shows as many elements as it contains. This is because the data is synchronized. Cannot set routing based on asynchronous data.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Although your data is async, the subscribe will only ever be called once the async data is resolved. So the data you get in your subscribe will not be async.  There is most likely incorrect data returned by your api if you are still not able to get the desired output. Your api should be returning the routes array. Check the network tab in your browser and show exactly what you're getting from the API. Also, in my example there is a console in ngOnInit, show what the prints in your console as well.

Comment: I explain all the time that it returns the route but sees it as empty.
If I type `console.log(this.router.config)` I can see the whole route. If I use `console.log(this.router.config [0])`, nothing will be displayed.
This is because there is no last constant value.
In the example you gave on stackbliz, you could set `.router.resetConfig()` out of `subscribe()`. If you used `http.get()` you have to emit the last constant value. `Observable.of()` emits the last constant value beyond `.subscribe()`. So your example using http.get will not work unless a constant value notification is emitted.

Comment: `class A{    public value; construct(){  of('').subscribe(data => this.value = data) ; router.resetConfig(this.value) ; console.log(this.value); }    }` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for APP_INITIALIZER. I can not found a good example but basically you defined a function in a service that return a promise

```
//in your service
loadData() {
    return this.httpClient.get(...)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res=>{
        this.data=res //<--here you store the response
  }
```

in your module.ts

```
export function init_app(myService: MyService) {
  return () => myService.loadData();
}

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [
         ...,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: init_app, deps: [MyService], multi: true }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

So, you can use myService.data in any component that inject the service because the first time Angular get the data

Answer (score 0):

The point is to download synchronized data, router.resetConfig({must be sync data}).
I was thinking about emitting the last value and saving it somehow. I'm trying to use .subscribeOn(), .observeOn() and Scheduler.